# cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'): and cv2.imwrite() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am following [this](https://github.com/jg-fisher/dinoAI) project to make a AI that plays Google Chrome Dino game. I am stuck at a point while capturing screen feed to generate training data. I am new to CV

The project is supposed to supposed to break the video feed and save the CSV file in cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'): condition. Which I believe is when key "q" is pressed. But nothing happens when I press 'q'. The print statement in this if condition doesn't print when I press q.

Also although the console prints the print statement in 'up' ,'down' or 't' key pressed condition but the

```
cv2.imwrite('./images/frame_(0).jpg'.format(x), img)
```

Doesn't seem to be working as no images in the images folder are saved.

Here is the code

```
import cv2 
from mss import mss 
import numpy as np 
import keyboard

#Captures dinasour run for given coordinates

def start():
    """
    Capture video feed frame by frame, crops out coods and the dino then process
    """

    sct = mss()

    coordinates = {
        'top': 168,
        'left': 230,
        'width': 624,
        'height': 141
    }

    with open('actions.csv','w') as csv:
        x = 0
        while True:
            img = np.array(sct.grab(coordinates))

            #crop out the dino from the image array
            img = img[::,75:624]

            #edge detection to reduce ammount of image processing work
            img = cv2.Canny(img, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)

            if keyboard.is_pressed('up arrow'):
                cv2.imwrite('./images/frame_(0).jpg'.format(x), img)
                csv.write('1\n')
                print('jump write')
                x += 1

            if keyboard.is_pressed('down arrow'):
                cv2.imwrite('./images/frame_(0).jpg'.format(x), img)
                csv.write('2\n')
                print('duck')
                x += 1


            if keyboard.is_pressed('t'):
                cv2.imwrite('./images/frame_(0).jpg'.format(x), img)
                csv.write('0\n')
                print('nothing')
                x += 1

            # break the video feed
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                csv.close()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                print('Exited')
                break

def play():
    sct = mss()

    coordinates = {
        'top': 168,
        'left': 230,
        'width': 624,
        'height': 141
    }

    img = np.array(sct.grab(coordinates))

    # crop out the dinosaur from the image array
    img = img[::,75:615]

    # edge detection to reduce amount of image processing work
    img = cv2.Canny(img, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cv2.waitKey()` does only work if you press the key while an OpenCV window (e.g. created with `cv2.imshow()`) is focused. It seems for me as you don't use GUI features of OpenCV at all.

If you have a OpenCV GUI in your program, focus it and then press the key.

If not, and if you don't want to implement one, why not use `keyboard.isPressed()`?